# lua script "IfKeyLockIsOn" help. Using laptop and dont want to use/have switches like numlock or capslock

Tags: lua, macros

The script I have activates when the NumLock switch is on. Im on laptop now so I want to use another key switch. Can someone help to replace switch to when touch pad is disabled?

Its a simple reduced recoil script.
Can I replace numlock to if touch pad is 'disabled'?
Any ideas?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("Numlock") then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
                Sleep(1)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

tried an easy fix and replaced with caps lock since my laptop doesnt have numlock. I keep hitting it and want to find another key switch to use.

Comment: How can you disable touchpad?

Comment: GHub can read: 1) Caps/Num/Scroll-Lock LEDs status, 2) Shift/Alt/Ctrl-keys (down/up), 3) all mouse buttons.  For example, you can switch recoil mode on/off with MouseButton#8.  Or with simultaneous LMB+RMB.  Or recoil may be on only while `Shift` key is kept down.  Or something else.  What would you like?

Comment: I can disable/enable my touch pad with Fn-F10

Comment: I would like to use numlock/scroll-lock but my laptop doesnt have such buttons. I tried caps lock but I kept accidentally hitting it. Just need a way for buttons to act as a on/off switch without getting in the way of gameplay.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can toggle recoil by pressing mouse button 8.

```
local is_active

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8 then
      is_active = not is_active
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and is_active then
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
         Sleep(1)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```